# О разумности параграфа один "Правил русской орфографии и пунктуации" 1956 года

Tags: орфография

В 1956 году в СССР были изданы "Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации", утверждённые АН СССР, Министерством высшего образования СССР и Министерством просвещения РСФСР.

В параграфе один указанных правил сказано: "После ж, ч, ш, щ не пишутся ю, я, ы, а пишутся у, а, и. Например: чудо, щука, час, роща, жир, шить."

Из изложенного следует, что указанные правила были адресованы лицам, которые писали "жюк" вместо "жук", "чясы" вместо "часы", "шюба" вместо "шуба", "щюка" вместо "щука".

Я предполагаю, что указанными лицами были пользователи русского языка, которые величали себя "советскими людьми", то есть представителями уже исчезнувшего "советского народа".

Мне не нравится вышеуказанное "правило". По моему мнению, русским следует писать:

- букву "а" вместо буквы "я" после букв "ч" и "щ" ("часы" вместо "чясы", "щавель" вместо "щявель" и т. п.),
- букву "у" вместо буквы "ю" после букв "ч" и "щ" ("чудо" вместо "чюдо", "щука" вместо "щюка" и т. п.),
- букву "ы" вместо буквы "и" после букв "ж" и "ш" ("жыр" вместо "жир", "шыло" вместо "шило" и т. п.).

А что думаете Вы по этому поводу, дорогие филологи?

Answer (score 1):

Существуют очень простые ПРАВИЛА РУССКОГО ПИСЬМА:

1) В русском языке 5  гласных звуков-знаков: А, О, У, Е, И. Эти пять звуков обозначаются
 5-ью парами гласных букв А/Я, О/Ё, У/Ю, Э/Е, Ы/И.

2) Звуки-знаки А, О, У, Е, И, стоящие после согласного, выбирают себе одну из парных букв А/Я, О/Ё, У/Ю, Э/Е, Ы/И, если НУЖНО ОБОЗНАЧИТЬ мягкость/твердость этого согласного.

3) Звуки-знаки А, О, У, Е, И обозначаются преимущественно ОДНОИМЕННЫМИ буквами А, О, У, Е, И, если выбирать мягкость/твердость  согласного НЕ НУЖНО, то есть после шипящих и Ц.

И если какой-нибудь маленький шалун не хочет эти правила понять и  выучить, то он получает заслуженную двойку.

Comment: Не исключено, что Академия наук СССР, Министерство высшего образования СССР и Министерство просвещения РСФСР руководствовались сказкой про "5 гласных звуков-знаков А, О, У, Е, И", которые "стоя после согласного, выбирают себе одну из парных букв А/Я, О/Ё, У/Ю, Э/Е, Ы/И, если НУЖНО ОБОЗНАЧИТЬ мягкость/твердость этого согласного" и т. п.

Comment: О нормировании в области орфографии серьезно стали задумываться в первой половине 18 века, когда написания ЧА-ЩА,ЧУ-ЩУ, ЖИ-ШИ уже СЛОЖИЛИСЬ. Написание ЖИ-ШИ отражает древнерусское произношение, когда шипящие согласные звуки Ж и Ш были мягкими.В 13 веке произошло отвердение звуков  Ж и Ш, но написание слов сохранилось прежним. Написание ЧА-ЩА,ЧУ-ЩУ также характерно для русского языка, но в церк-сл. языке встречались написания чюти (чуять), чюдо.

Comment: Таковы ТРАДИЦИИ, которые в современном языке переосмыслены в соответствии фонематическим принципом письма (сказкой в Вашем понимании), когда буквами обозначаются фонемы (звуки-знаки из сказки).

Comment: Принял к сведению, что:

1) "написание ЖИ-ШИ отражает древнерусское произношение" [древнерусского человека], но не отражает произношение ЖЫ-ШЫ [русского человека],

2) "написание ЧА-ЩА, ЧУ-ЩУ ... характерно для русского языка".

Comment: Древнерусское произношение присутствует в нашей современной жизни, хотя мы это не всегда замечаем. Помните у Есенина: "Не жалею, не зову, не плачу..." Вы задумывались, какой звук и почему вы произносите после согласного Ж? А окончание ОГО/ЕГО, ОМ/ЕМ, когда ЕГО,ЕМ пишется после МЯГКИХ согласных, шипящих и Ц? Это всё память о том, что когда-то они ВСЕ были мягкие, и с этим связано их желание держаться единой группой.

Comment: Прочитано про "их желание держаться единой группой".

Comment: А штамп поставлен? А подписью скреплено? А прошнуровано? А в архив сдано? А Niemand-у доложено?

Comment: Прочитано про "штамп", "подпись", "архив" и т. п.

Answer (score 0):

> **А что думаете Вы по этому поводу**
> Разве государство на протяжении последних (ого, без малого 100) 97 лет спрашивало мнение людей? И собственно, пока тот самый "человек" советский верховодит, ничего не изменится. 
> А по теме - менять уже поздно, прижилось, опять переходный период, снова буча, раскол среди филологов, и прочее-прочее.